# xapk file validation failed - After downdloading obb file

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I am getting error "xapk file validation faild" after successfully download an obb file.

A progress reach at 99% then give an error "xapk file validation faild".

I debugging a code and then it thrown an exception "Not a zip archived" from

```
ZipResourceFile zrf = new ZipResourceFile(fileName);
```

in ZipResocuceFile,

```
void addPatchFile(String zipFileName) throws IOException {
  int header = read4LE(f);
        if (header == kEOCDSignature) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Found Zip archive, but it looks empty");
            throw new IOException();
        } else if (header != kLFHSignature) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Not a Zip archive");
            throw new IOException();
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645069/obb-file-are-not-extract-error-is-xapk-file-validation-failed

Comment: Please, give me answer of this question if you know.

Answer (score 2):

Also i have tried with ZipResourceFile but i had the same error.
You can try to mount and unmount your obb file with this class:
https://gist.github.com/Clockers/11af3c136b5d283f3560

My obb is created using JObb on a folder containing the file, you can find it here:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/jobb.html

Comment: Hello, Larenzo Salani
Thank you for giving you positive response,
Please, send me details where can i add ObbManager class reference and if you have sample code how to implement ObbManager in my existing code then please send me

I am getting this error from ZipResourceFile class, so can i replace this by mount unmount process.

Thank you

Comment: Remember that your application must have the same version of the .obb file.

Comment: thank you for your response, i am implemented you reference link code but how can i use files which are in obb file in my application

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution,
create obb file without using of jobb command, using jobb command it create encrypted obb file, there is no need to create encrypted obb file

I am uploading unencrypted obb file to playstore,
here, are steps to create unencrypted obb file

1. copy you resources files into a folder
2. create zip file of your resource folder (main.[version_code].[package_name].zip)
3. rename your zip folder with name (main.[version_code].[package_name].obb)

now, obb file is ready to upload on play store

Its help for me